# Django AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SubfieldBase'

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu, django-models

I'm working on an django project that was created using an older version of django. My environment is set up for the latest django version (1.11.4). 
when I try `python manage.py runserver`, I get this:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 228, in wrapper
>
> ```
> fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> ```
>
> line 117, in inner_run
>
> ```
> autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> ```
>
> line 251, in raise_last_exception
>
> ```
> six.reraise(*_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> ```
>
> line 228, in wrapper
>
> ```
> fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27,
> ```
>
> in setup
>
> ```
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
> ```
>
> 108, in populate
>
> ```
> app_config.import_models()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line
> ```
>
> 202, in import_models
>
> ```
> self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
> __import__(name)   File
> ```
>
> "/home/ahmedn1/Documents/Paymob/wallet_executive_panel-master-c109bd6fe9cd1bf793c11a5c2e97d18a1887c3ba/accounts/models.py",
>   line 8, in
>
> ```
> import timedelta   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/timedelta/__init__.py", line
> ```
>
> 11, in
>
> ```
> from .fields import TimedeltaField   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/timedelta/fields.py", line 18,
> ```
>
> in
>
> ```
> class TimedeltaField(six.with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.Field)): AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
> ```
>
> 'SubfieldBase'

So, it seems the problem is with the django-timedeltafield package. I have the latest (0.7.10) version of that package. So, I don't understand why it still has an issue with the deprecated SubfieldBase.

Any ideas how I might solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The django-timedelta-field package does not work with Django 1.10+. From the [django-timedelta-field](https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-timedelta-field/) repo:

> If you are using Django 1.8 or greater (and you really *should* be), then you should use the included [`DurationField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) instead of this.
>
> This field does not work with Django 1.10, and will probably not be updated to fix the issue(s).

Here's the explanation of the deprecation of `SubFieldBase` from the [1.8 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase).

Comment: yes but that piece of code is inside the django modules itself. It is not in my project. 
How do I change this?

I mean the `from .fields import TimedeltaField   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/timedelta/fields.py", line 18,`

Comment: I don't understand your question. The advice is to use `DurationField()` instead of `django-timedelta-field` with Django 1.10+. If you do want to use django-timedelta-field, you'll have to clone the repository and modify the code before installing it.

Comment: Ok I got it. I removed all imports of timedelta and used instead models.DurationField in the migration files. 

This solved the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair both fields are for different use right? TimeZoneField and DurationField

Comment: @RanjuR I don't think this question has anything to do with `TimeZoneField`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred when the Django version got upgrade due to a package install.
You might want to run 'pip install -r requirements.txt' which will install the Django version that is compatible with your exisiting project.

So try , pip install -r requirements.txt

Let me know if it works for you as well.